# How to retrieve the "it" block status and based on the result i need to upload screenshot in ALM

Tags: javascript, protractor

In my project in one spec file, multiple it blocks would be there. So while executing the spec,i need to retrieve the PASS/FAIL status of  "it" block and based on the result i have to perfrom some operations like uploading screenshot in ALM.

I have tried Spec done to retrieve the pass or fail status.but in AfterEach() i need to upload screenshot based on the Pass or fail status. I am not sure how to get and pass the "it" block execution status and use the same in  afterEach() to continue Pass or Fail validation.

exclude the ALM part of code for now. The attached code is now printing the afterEach() console statement multiple time.

```
>For first it block it is printing for one time.
>After second it block execution, it is printing twice
>After third it block execution, it is printing thrice.
Not sure why it printing multiple time ,as after Each is expected to run once after "it" block in spec file.
```

Result from commandprompt:
.Name: TestSuite1 Testcase1-POM type1
I am Passed: it01
.Name: TestSuite1 Step-entering credentials-step2
I am Passed: it01

Name: TestSuite1 Step-entering credentials-step2
I am Passed: it01

.Name: TestSuite1 step3
I am Passed: it01
Name: TestSuite1 step3
I am Passed: it01
Name: TestSuite1 step3
I am Passed: it01

Could someone please help ,why it is printing multiple times in protractor.

## Below is my code:

```
var exceldata=require("../CommonMethods/ExcelRead.js");
var homepage= require("../PageObjects/HomePage.js");
var Exeresults;
var fs= require('fs');
var LandingPage;
var BaristaNewWindowPage;

var Testitblock;
var Testitblockstatus;
var Testsuite;

var JasmineTestContainerSupport = window.JasmineTestContainerSupport || require('jasmine-test-container-support');

JasmineTestContainerSupport.extend(jasmine);


if(exceldata.Mytest.test1==="Yes"){
    describe('TestSuite1',function()
            {


        beforeAll(function()
                {
            browser.get(exceldata.MyURL.testurl1);
            console.log("Posse URL is launched successfully");
                });

        it('Testcase1-POM type1',function()
                {
            try{
                homepage.clickingPosseLink();
            }catch(err){
                console.log("error occured in first step of it block")
            }

                });

        it('Step-entering credentials-step2',function(){

            homepage.entercredintal("test1@gmail.com", "Sudhar@12345");


        });

        it('step3',function()
                {
            try{
                LandingPage=homepage.clickingSubmit();
            }catch(err){
                console.log("error occured in third step of it block")
            }

                });
        xit('step4',function()
                {
            try{`enter code here`
                BaristaNewWindowPage=LandingPage.navigateBaristaURL();
                //expect(1).toequal(2);
            }catch(err){
                console.log("error occured in fourth step of it block")
            }

                });
        xit('step5',function()
                {
            try{
                BaristaNewWindowPage.BaristaOurStoryLnk();  
            }catch(err){
                console.log("error occured in fifth step of it block")
            }

                }); 



        afterEach(function(){

            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new function() {
                this.specDone = function(result) {
                    //status = result.failedExpectations.length > 0 ? "Fail" : "Pass";
                    console.log('Name: ' + result.fullName);
                    if (result.failedExpectations.length > 0) {
                        console.log('I am Failed: it01');
                        status = "Fail";
                        notes = result.failedExpectations;
                    }else{
                        console.log('I am Passed: it01');
                        status = "Pass";
                        notes = "";
                    }
                };

            });
        });
            });

}
```

Comment: oh boy... this question again Lol yeah, everyone wants to find a way to do that, but the sad truth is it's impossible... kind of. My best assay on this topic so far is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56898145/is-there-a-way-to-run-particular-protractor-test-depending-on-the-result-of-the/56905639#56905639 if it helps you, please upvote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to run particular Protractor test depending on the result of the other test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56898145/is-there-a-way-to-run-particular-protractor-test-depending-on-the-result-of-the)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can implement logger [log4Js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js-protractor-appender) library to get all test passed/Failed status in log
2. You can use external report
   library [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-beautiful-reporter)

I am currentlly using in my framework