# Can we establish dependency between spec file in protractor using jasmine?

Tags: protractor, jasmine-node, protractor-net

In my project the ask is , we need to establish the dependency between the spec files.
Each spec file is having multiple it block. So if any it  block failed, the spec should return failed, and the dependent specfile should not run as part of execution.

Is there any way to establish the dependency between spec file in protractor using jasmine framework?

Tried multiple blogs, but nowhere i found the expected answer.

Comment: If one `it` block fails, and whole execution stops, will that work for you? or you'll need to skip certain spec files while the others should be still ran?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve the "it" block status and based on the result i need to upload screenshot in ALM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57787833/how-to-retrieve-the-it-block-status-and-based-on-the-result-i-need-to-upload-s)

Comment: @Sergey----->We have multiple Spec files, and for our scenario, if spec file 2 is failed which is related to Creation functionality, Spec 3[which is related to update] ,Update should get skipped.We wanted to establish this in protractor. Suggesstions are highly helpful.Spec 4 and other files should run as expected. We mainly wanted to skip the spec file by creating  dependency between two files.

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56905639/9150146, I revised it for your case