# How to stop protractor execution only if login failed but run all tests normally if login passes

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am using Protractor to run tests on a login-based web application on CI with around 1000 tests running daily. It was all going well until all my tests started to fail. The reason is that the web-based app depends upon login, and due to a minor issue with the app, login failed, followed by that all my tests failed and it took 8hrs to complete! This was a big mess. I started to wonder how can I avoid such failures. I found Protractor's **fail-fast** mode but it did no good because it would stop execution on the first failure. I want something that stops the execution as soon as login fails but runs all the tests (irrespective of any failure) if login passes. Is there a way to work this out?
Tests are run in docker in headless mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two guys are your friends: `await browser.close();` & `await process.exit(1);`

Never really thoughts about it, but seems like I'll need to implement this too in my login method

```
async login(username, password, quitOnFailure = true) {
  // do what you normally do to login
  await sendKeys(this.$usernameInput, username);
  await sendKeys(this.$passwordInput, password);
  await this.$submitButton.click();
  await this.waitForLoad();

  // lets says if for testing purposes you need to continue on failure 
  // and check certain scenarios make this optional
  if (quitOnFailure) {

    // in my case if I'm not logged in I get a red label displayed
    if (await this.$errorLabel.isPresent()) {
      await browser.close();
      await process.exit(1);
    }

    // this may be your way for checking if you're not logged in
    // try to wait until a welcome message is present, if not, quit
    try {
      await browser.wait(
        ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(homePage.$welcomeMessage),
        10000,
        `Failed at ${__file} -> ${__function}() -> line ${__line}`
      )
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      await browser.close();
      await process.exit(1);
    }
  }
};
``'
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot @Sergey! I like async and await for this. Can we also create dependency on tests using async/await? For example, 
it('test1'){...} 
it('test2 depends upon test1'){if test1 pass then only execute test2, else execute test3}
it('test3'){...}

Comment: I understand your test cases should not depend on one other. And that is why i believe protractor does not have any such feature. But many at times, especially in my scenario, where there are 30-40 tests in a flow and they depend upon one mandatory field,  I don't have a choice. I would love to have something that can handle this kind of scenarios, if at all it's possible. Thanks.

Comment: you're welcome, glad it helped. I totally get it why you may need this feature in your tests and there IS a way to do that, though it's a bit ugly. Check out my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56905639/9150146

Comment: These are the best possible solutions I have seen so far for running dependent tests in Protractor. Great work. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I handle this in my CI environment by adding a BVT step. I use jenkins to do so, I cerated a Pipeline in Which before starting the entire Test suite, I just run BVT Job, in which I just run Login test. If BVT is pass next step is to Run full test suite, but if BVT is failed next step will not even execute.