# Protractor - getting the getText out of it block

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I get the text by using the getText method and compare it with another text. 
I cannot use the if-else block outside of it block to compare two strings.
If I insert the if-else block into it block, it works fine, but I cannot use drinkDropdownMenu(); function (which contains 15 it blocks) inside it block

```
  import {beverageDropdownMenu} from '../e2e/customBeforeRunAuto/bevSetDropDownMenu';

  describe('Should check the bev set before opening the bev pop up menu', function() 
  {
    var setName;

    it("should check the name", function () 
    {
        activebeverageSet.getText().then(function(text)
        {
            console.log('set name is ' + text);
            setName = text;
        });
    });

    if(setName == getBeverageSetFromSetup)
    {
        it('checking the beverage set is finish', () => 
        {
            console.log('\nThe beverege set ' + setName + ' is selected\n');
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('\nThe beverege set ' + setName + ' is new one\n');
        beverageDropdownMenu();
    } 
});
```

I can put inside the else 160 lines of code without 15 it blocks and solve the problem but in the future, it will be difficult to maintain the code.

```
   it('should compare the beverage set', () => 
    {
        if(setName == getBeverageSetFromSetup)
        {
            console.log('\nThe beverege set ' + setName + ' is selected\n');
            console.log('\nThe beverege set ' + getBeverageSetFromSetup + ' is chosen\n');
        }
        else
        { 
            console.log('\nThe beverege set ' + setName + ' is displayed\n');
            console.log('\nThe beverege set ' + getBeverageSetFromSetup + ' is chosen\n');
            beverageDropdownMenu();
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how jasmine builds describe and it blocks. This answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/56905639/9150146